# Deprecate full package in Scala/Java

Tags: java, scala

I need to deprecate the full package. I can do it by writing `@Deprecated` annotation in each class.

Is there a way to deprecate full package in Scala at once, without using `@Deprecated` annotation for each class?

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently [is not possible to deprecate an entire scala package](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3115).

Answer (score 2):

Add a `package-info.java` file in the package that you want to deprecate and then add the annotation:

```
@Deprecated
package your.package.name
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for Java, but for Scala deprecating of package objects still is not supported.

Comment: I tried this and two things, first you're missing a `';'` after the package name, and second it doesn't work with Scala files that use either Scala nor Java classes inside that package.